# function keeps thinking parameter list is full of secondary functions

Tags: c++, validation, compiler-errors

Whenever I run my header file, the program keeps throwing an error saying that: error: expected ')' before ',' token (referring to my class constructor). However, when I delete the first variable, it throws the error for the previously second variable. Please help.

```
#ifndef STACKARRAYSECURITY_h
#define STACKARRAYSECURITY_h
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


template <class stacktype>
class stackarray {
private:
    std::string password = "NULL";
    unsigned long int maxsize, stacktop;
    stacktype * stackarrayptr;
    bool setpassword(std::string newpassword);
    bool allowdynamic = false;
public:
    bool accessdynamics(std::string iptpassword);
    stackarray(password, maxsize = 0) {
        stackarrayptr = new stacktype[maxsize];
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: You need to specify the type of `password` and `maxsize` as the parameters of the constructor.

Comment: Constructor must be `stackarray(const std::string& password, unsigned long maxsize = 0)`

Comment: thing is, those were already defined beforehand

Comment: Parameters (of constructor) and member variables, they're not the same thing. If you give them the same names, then in the body of the constructor, parameters will *hide* the member variables with same name.

Comment: @songyuanyao what do you mean? Wouldn't the values inputted just be assigned to password and maxsize?

Comment: Or would they have to be pass by reference

Comment: The arguments will be used to initialize parameters; you have to initialize member variables by yourself, e.g. `stackarray(const std::string& password, unsigned long maxsize = 0) : password(password), maxsize(maxsize) { ... }`. Or more clear: `stackarray(const std::string& pw, unsigned long ms = 0) : password(pw), maxsize(mx) { ... }`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can't pass previously defined member variables into member functions as parameters--I have to create new variables into the parameter list and then set the previously defined member variables equal...right?